# Creating an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript

I'm having a few problems with the following:

```
Dim design(6) As String

design(0) = "DES1"
design(1) = "DES1_slot"
design(2) = "DES2"
design(3) = "DES2_slot"
design(4) = "DES3"
design(5) = "DES3_slot"
```

I get the error "Expected end of statement"

Similarly:

```
Dim design(0 To 5) As String

design(0) = "DES1"
design(1) = "DES1_slot"
design(2) = "DES2"
design(3) = "DES2_slot"
design(4) = "DES3"
design(5) = "DES3_slot"
```

says "Expecting ')' "

I don't often use VBA, but from the quick googling I did at least one of these should work?

Comment: Which line is the error on? Just checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats perfectly valid *VBA* however you will get those exact errors in *VBScript* which is what I presume your using.

As VBScript is typeless change the first line to just:

```
Dim design(5)
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, as I said, I don't use it much so I had no idea :)

Comment: Actually, you should use `Dim design(5)` since you define the upper-bound in VB/VBA/VBScript. Using `5` will create a six-element array (`0-5`)which is what you apparently need.